# What features does every map in Don't Starve have?

Tags: dont-starve, reign-of-giants

As far as I know, every default Reign of Giants map has the following:

- At least one instance of every [biome](http://dontstarve.wikia.com/wiki/Biomes)
- At least one Pig King.
- At least one (usually 2-3) [Totally Normal Trees](http://dontstarve.wikia.com/wiki/Totally_Normal_Tree)
- [Maxwell's Door](http://dontstarve.wikia.com/wiki/Maxwell%27s_Door), and the five "Things" used to activate it.

#### What other *special* game elements are spawned naturally in every map?

By "special", I am ignoring things like type of tree, monsters, plants, boons, etc. Including all of those would make this question far too open.

I *am* thinking of set pieces or unique items -- things like:

- [Glommer's Statue](http://dontstarve.wikia.com/wiki/Glommer's_Statue)
- The small farm set piece (several Basic farms, carrots, twigs, and grass tufts, and usually (always?) the [Metal Potato Thing](http://dontstarve.wikia.com/wiki/Metal_Potato_Thing))
- Pig village(s)
- Mandrakes -- the only non-unique item I'm including on this list
- The [Eye Bone](http://dontstarve.wikia.com/wiki/Eye_Bone)
- Others....??

Comment: "Only single item in this list" - do you mean only 'non' single item? As there can be many mandrakes, but not multiple Glommer Statues or Eye Bones - IIRC

Comment: Thanks. I updated it to clarify. There are multiple mandrakes on maps (AFAIK), and that's the only special item/set piece with multiplicity on that list. Otherwise, I'm only thinking of structures/plants/rocks/monsters/mobs/etc. -- besides seasonal Giants -- that are unique and included in each and every map by default.

Comment: You've confused [Maxwell's Door](http://dontstarve.wikia.com/wiki/Maxwell's_Door) and the [Teleportato](http://dontstarve.wikia.com/wiki/Wooden_Thing), which is another word for the wooden thing. Maxwells door is open as soon as you find it, and leads to adventure mode. The Teleportato is possible to activate by bringing 4 things to the wooden thing, and can be used to reset your world.

Comment: On the subject of things, there are 5. The wooden thing is the base, however, and cannot be moved. The wooden thing spawns with clockworks and marble trees, the metal potato thing spawns with farms and a shovel, the crank thing spawns with a pig hut and spiky tree, the ring thing spawns in a ring of evil flowers, and the box thing spawns surrounded by walls, with a spear and gnome.

Answer (score 1):

I can't list all of them for sure, but I know there is always 3 plugged sinkholes, which lead to the caves. One spawns in the birchnut forest, near pig king. One spawns somewhere in the patchwork biome. One spawns in a forest in the center of your swamp. Some guy in the comments of the wiki page on wormholes also said there's 3 pairs of wormholes per world, but I'm not sure if that's true.